# use mailx to send mail, but cannot receive mail sometimes

Tags: shell, mailx

my os is cent os 6.4, mailx is Heirloom Mail version 12.4 7/29/08.

The mailx works fine before. But when I send 2 attachments which size is about 500kB in one mail , I cannot receive mail at most time. But if I tried again and again I may receive the mail.

When I send the mail in terminal, it did not output any error message.

So where can I see the mails error log? or any one know something about it?